# MySQL union, joins & limit

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, union

I have the following query:

```
SELECT result.globalId AS id, result.date, p1.playerName AS player, p2.playerName AS   target, w.weaponIngameName AS weapon, result.headshot, s.serverName AS server, result.origin
FROM (
(

SELECT globalId, date, serverId, playerId, targetId, weaponId, headshot, 'playerkills' AS origin
FROM playerkills
WHERE (
playerkills.playerId =976
OR playerkills.targetId =976
)
ORDER BY date DESC
)
UNION (

SELECT globalId, date, serverId, playerId, NULL , NULL , NULL , 'playersuicides' AS origin
FROM playersuicides
WHERE (
playersuicides.playerId =976
)
ORDER BY date DESC
)
)result
LEFT JOIN players p1 ON result.playerId = p1.playerId
LEFT JOIN players p2 ON result.targetId = p2.playerId
LEFT JOIN weapons w ON result.weaponId = w.weaponId
LEFT JOIN servers s ON result.serverId = s.serverId
ORDER BY result.date DESC , result.globalId DESC
```

And I want to limit the `result` union to have a maximum of 300 results, before any of the `JOIN`s are being applied. How do I accomplish this?

Simply adding `LIMIT 300` after `(...) result` does not work, it gives the following MySQL error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN players p1 ON result.playerId = p1.playerId LEFT JOIN players p2 ON r' at line 9`

Comment: Can you update the question with the MySQL error that you are getting?

Comment: @ChrisMcCauley Updated on request.

Comment: maybe try `AS result` instead of just `result` immediately before `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @NickJ That neither works, and if it would work it would be more a bug in `MySQL` I believe. Such things should not change the outcome of a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When changing the query to the following, it does work:

```
SELECT result.globalId AS id, result.date, p1.playerName AS player, p2.playerName AS   target, w.weaponIngameName AS weapon, result.headshot, s.serverName AS server, result.origin
FROM (
(

SELECT globalId, date, serverId, playerId, targetId, weaponId, headshot, 'playerkills' AS origin
FROM playerkills
WHERE (
playerkills.playerId =976
OR playerkills.targetId =976
)
ORDER BY date DESC
)
UNION (

SELECT globalId, date, serverId, playerId, NULL , NULL , NULL , 'playersuicides' AS origin
FROM playersuicides
WHERE (
playersuicides.playerId =976
)
ORDER BY date DESC
) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 300) result
LEFT JOIN players p1 ON result.playerId = p1.playerId
LEFT JOIN players p2 ON result.targetId = p2.playerId
LEFT JOIN weapons w ON result.weaponId = w.weaponId
LEFT JOIN servers s ON result.serverId = s.serverId
ORDER BY result.date DESC , result.globalId DESC
```

Note that I added the `ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 300` before calling the table `result`, so now the following happens roughly:

1) Individual `SELECT`s inside `UNION` are being ran.

2) `UNION` is used to combine the results.

3) The `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` is being applied to the `UNION`.

4) The `UNION` is named as `result`.

5) The rest of the query happens.